# Wordpress Migration - Issue with admin panel changes

Tags: database, wp-admin, migration

I wanted an exact replica of my current wordpress website on a different domain with a different database.

So I created a database in same db host as the original database.I changed siteurl and homeurl in new database to the corresponding new domain.

I dumped the same code to new IP and changed wp_config file i.e. dbname,dbuser and wp_home wp_siteurl. I kept db_host same as I have both the databases on same host.

I was able to get the replica up on new domain,but I am facing following issue - whenever I change my password for admin in new admin panel , it gets reflected in my original website database and vice a versa.

Similar thing is happening for advanced custom fields in my admin panels.If I change something in new admin panel,it is reflected on my original website.

And also I noticed a very important thing...whenever I log into admin panel of my new website..I get those changes in both the websites...So I guess currently this depends on which admin panel I log into...

What could be the issue?? I think I have followed all the guidelines of wordpress migration to other domain.

Comment: You made a mistake somewhere and both sites are using the same database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your sites are using same database.

If you have time to do it again, you can try moving your website by using plugin [All-in-One WP Migration](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)